# Asp.Net Impersonation Fails On First Try But Succeeds on Second

Tags: asp.net, impersonation, rdlc

We are using RDLC's in a Asp.net web application. For reasons beyond our understanding, the first call to the database server fails with the following error:

> An error has occurred during report processing.
>   Cannot open database "TryParkingIt2" requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'EXTRANET\OurServerNameHere$'.

Run the report again, it works.

Huh?

**Update** Click the button the first time, it fails. Click the button again, it works. The account being impersonated is a domain account. Also, this error occurs on all five different report pages, which is why I didn't include any code.

Comment: Are you referring to the first and second calls within the same impersonation context? Within the same method?  Within the same page request?

Comment: Can you tell us how you are impersonating?

Comment: 1) When it succeeds, what identity is it using to connect to SQL? You can see this in SQL profiler. 2) Is there any reason you prefer integrated auth over sql auth?

Comment: I don't prefer integrated auth, the DBA does :)

Comment: What does the code look like that executes when you click the button.  You ask a good question, but the details are scant.

Comment: I didn't add the code because there are five different reports that have this same problem, each with different code in the event handler that generates the report.

Comment: Are you impersonating with `identity impersonate=true` in the `web.config` file, or are you impersonating using `Identity.Impersonate` in your code?

Comment: We are using identity impersonate=true in web.config.

Answer (score 1):

Look for static constructors or global.asax code that is failing.  Those are run only once when the application starts up (actually for static constructors are run when the class is first accessed), so often they will cause a failure the first time, and then everything seems to work fine after that (even though something is really busted up in the background).

BTW, this is a GREAT reason to avoid static constructors.